# localhost not loading image from search results - phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost

localhost for phpmydmin shows image folder and image links but it does not load the images. The loading page goes from the directory to a blank page. It seemed to happen overnight without any changes to the system or any updates. I have a search function in my project and php shows the search results without populating the image onto page.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: Sure there is something you can do. You can start looking for what the actual issue is. Start by looking into your http servers error log file. That is where you can _read_ what the issue is.

Comment: I checked and this comes up since the errors 'www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name'

Comment: I checked the errors and tried running with Administrator rights but the error still persists

Comment: Mate, you were quite short and sweet with your suggestion. But I did what you suggested and that lead to changing the listening port and problem is now fixed. It was driving me crazy as everything else was working except the image not loading. Thank you for your help

Comment: Fine to hear that you sorted out your issue. I wonder what port you actually used, though... Port 443 is standard for https, but I have no idea what `443:0` is meant to be.

Comment: I used 8080 and 4433